# Return Request in Spring API

Tags: java, spring, request, response, okhttp

My program calls an external API. Now I want to return this response directly to the user without any changes. But instead of the response where Im supposed to see the header and body, I only get this response:

```
 {
    "redirect": false,
    "successful": true
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {

        return response;
    }
```

When I look at the response object in debug mode, I get all the information I want. Why can't the user see it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The try block automatically closes the response when leaving its scope. Mitigate by reading the response inside that block or getting rid of the try block.